# Equinox and OSGI bundles

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, bundles

I am trying to understand how Equinox works by looking through its underlying bundles.

Can someone explain in general terms (or point out a good resource to understand) the relationship/difference between the `org.eclipse.osgi` and org.eclipse.equinox series of bundles? From what I understand `org.eclipse.osgi` contains the base OSGI runtime implementation and `org.eclipse.equinox` implements additional services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's the other way around. The package `org.eclipse.osgi` manages internals and imlements some services (but not all, see the list here: http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/bundles/). The `org.eclipse.equinox` bundle represents the whole framework and is responsible for managing the bundles and has the lowest start level.

Comment: Incorrect. `org.eclipse.osgi` is the OSGi Framework implementation. It's the core of the core. The `org.eclipse.equinox.*` bundles are still very low-level, but not inner core, functionality.

Comment: Is there a public Maven repo where I can get the Equinox bundles? Maven Central and the Sonatype repos don't have most of the bundles mentioned in the Equinox/bundles page.

Comment: I don't think that you can use maven directly, see Eclipse Tycho: http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/